# How do I hide a menu item automatically on all pages?

Tags: html, menu, hide

I have a website, about 10 HTML pages, all have the same menu, something like

```
<ul class="nav-menu">
                    <li><a href="page1.html">Page1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page2.html">Page2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page3.html">Page3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page4.html">Page4</a></li>
                </ul>
```

and so on.

Now, one of the pages is an event page, so when there are no events, I want to hide it. 
I would use the style property

```
<li style="display:none;"><a href="page1.html">Page1</a></li>
```

I would like to add or remove this style attribute only in one place, but it should automatically change on the other pages, so I don't have to do it manually for all the 10 pages (and subpages)

Is this possible? 
Any advice is welcomed! :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you page is reloaded every time that you change the page, you can to use this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var parts = url.split('/');
    var page = parts[parts.length - 1];
    
  switch(page){
    case 'page1.html':
      document.getElementById('p1').style.display = 'none';
      break;
    case 'page2.html':
      document.getElementById('p2').style.display = 'none';
      break;
    case 'page3.html':
      document.getElementById('p3').style.display = 'none';
      break;
    case 'page4.html':
      document.getElementById('p4').style.display = 'none';
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="Here js file route"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="nav-menu">
       <li id="p1"><a href="page1.html">Page1</a></li>
       <li id="p2"><a href="page2.html">Page2</a></li>
       <li id="p3"><a href="page3.html">Page3</a></li>
       <li id="p4"><a href="page4.html">Page4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! I am kind of new to webdesign. So, do I create a javascript file with the  script you gave me ? and add in the HTML <head> section   <script src="js/myjava.js"></script> ?  So I only edit myjava each time I need to hide/show a menu item. Does it work that way?

Comment: Yes, you can to do it like this.I updated the code, adding window.onload function